# Getting monkeypatching in pytest to work

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I'm trying to develop a test using pytest for a class method that randomly selects a string from a list of strings.

It looks essentially like the givemeanumber method below:

```
import os.path
from random import choice

class Bob(object):
  def getssh():
    return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~admin"), '.ssh')

  def givemeanumber():
    nos = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    chosen = choice(nos)
    return chosen
```

the first method, getssh, in the class Bob is just the example from the [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html)

My production code fetches a list of strings from a DB and then randomly selects one. So I'd like my test to fetch the strings and then instead of randomly selecting, it selects the first string. That way I can test against a known string.

From my reading I reckon I need to use monkeypatching to fake the randomisation.

Here's what I've got so far

```
import os.path
from random import choice
from _pytest.monkeypatch import MonkeyPatch
from bob import Bob

class Testbob(object):
    monkeypatch = MonkeyPatch()

    def test_getssh(self):
        def mockreturn(path):
            return '/abc'
        Testbob.monkeypatch.setattr(os.path, 'expanduser', mockreturn)
        x = Bob.getssh()
        assert x == '/abc/.ssh'

    def test_givemeanumber(self):
        Testbob.monkeypatch.setattr('random.choice',  lambda x: x[0])
        z = Bob.givemeanumber()
        assert z == 1
```

The first test method is again the example from the pytest docs (adapted slightly as I'm using it in a test class). This works fine.

Following the example from the docs I would expect to use 
`Testbob.monkeypatch.setattr(random, 'choice',  lambda x: x[0])`
but this yields 
`NameError: name 'random' is not defined`

if I change it to
`Testbob.monkeypatch.setattr('random.choice',  lambda x: x[0])`

it gets further but no swapping out occurs:
`AssertionError: assert 2 == 1`

Is monkeypatching the right tool for the job? 
If it is where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `import random` before monkeypatching, as it is done for `os.path`?

Comment: `import random.choice` instead of `from random import choice` and adjust your code accordingly. But I'd rather use dependency injection and avoid monkey-patching.

Comment: You cannot `import random.choice`, as this syntax is only for modules, and `choice` is a function. It will just fail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem comes from how the variables names are handled in Python. The key difference from other languages is that there is NO assigments of the values to the variables by their name; there is only binding of the variables' names to the objects.

This is a bigger topic out of scope of this question, but the consequence is as follows:

1. When you import a function `choice` from the module `random`, you bind a name `choice` to the function that exists there at the moment of import, and place this name in the local namespace of the `bob` module.
2. When you patch the `random.choice`, you re-bind the name `choice` of module `random` to the new mock object.
3. However, the already imported name in the `bob` module still refers to the original function. Because nobody patched it. The function itself was NOT modified, just the name was replaced.
4. So, the `Bob` class calls the original `random.choice` function, not the mocked one.

To solve this problem, you can follow one of two ways (but not both, as they are conflicting):

---

A: Always call `random.choice()` function by that exact full name (i.e. not `choice`). And, of course, `import random` before (not `from random import ...`) — same as you do for `os.path.expanduser()`.

```
# bob.py
import os.path
import random

class Bob(object):
  @classmethod
  def getssh(cls):
    return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~admin"), '.ssh')

  @classmethod
  def givemeanumber(cls):
    nos = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    chosen = random.choice(nos)   # <== !!! NOTE HERE !!!!
    return chosen
```

---

B: Patch the actual function that you call, which is `bob.choice()`  in that case (not `random.choice()`).

```
# test.py
import os.path
from _pytest.monkeypatch import MonkeyPatch
from bob import Bob

class Testbob(object):
    monkeypatch = MonkeyPatch()

    def test_givemeanumber(self):
        Testbob.monkeypatch.setattr('bob.choice',  lambda x: x[0])
        z = Bob.givemeanumber()
        assert z == 1
```

---

Regarding your original error with unknown name `random`: If you watn to `patch(random, 'choice', ...)`, then you have to `import random` — i.e. bind the name `random` to the module which is being patched.

When you do just `from random import choice`, you bind the name `choice`, but not `random` to the local namespace of the variables.

Comment: Thanks for this. I found patching memoization.cached that only your option A worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I landed on this question because I wanted to get MonkeyPatch working.

To get it working, you don't write `from _pytest.monkeypatch import MonkeyPatch`.  The leading underscore is a hint this is an internal method.

If you look at the [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/_modules/_pytest/monkeypatch.html), MonkeyPatch is a **fixture**.

```
import pytest


def test_some_foobar_env_var(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv("SOME_ENV_VAR", "foobar")
    assert something
```

More about `fixtures` [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html).